# Why does the amount of used heap decrease when the heap size increases?

Tags: java

I'm reading a large text file into an ArrayDeque,

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fname));
    String line=null;
    //allocate an ArrayDeque with enough room for 50M lines.
    ArrayDeque<String[]> inMemory = new ArrayDeque<String[]>(50000000);
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
        String[] lineArr = line.split("\t");
        inMemory.add(lineArr);
    }
    br.close();
```

I run it with

```
java -server -Xmx128g -cp target/stackoverflowquestion-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.stackoverflow.Question
```

While I run the code I open up [visualvm](http://visualvm.java.net/) and watch how the memory gets used up:

[image: visualvm]

Why does the amount of used heap periodically decrease?

**edit:** I changed the String[] to String. Now it does not happen. The lineArrs don't go away on each loop iteration.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fname));
String line=null;
//allocate an ArrayDeque with enough room for 50M lines.
ArrayDeque<String> inMemory = new ArrayDeque<String>(50000000);
while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    inMemory.add(line);
}
br.close();
```

[image]

Comment: Sure, any idea what is being collected?

Comment: hmmm... garbage? :) http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.es/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html

Comment: Unreferenced objects?

Comment: Have you seen that behavior consistently over multiple runs?

Comment: @DaveNewton So, I suppose that ArrayDeque is making several objects that it later unreferences?

Comment: @ajp15243 yes, but I only bother to look at the heap when the file is big

Comment: @rcompton We know almost nothing about your code, so it's impossible to say. There are `lineArr`s, the file buffer (don't know how it's implemented), who knows what else. If there's any resizing that would be a good-sized chunk of memory as well.

Comment: @DaveNewton good point, it could be the lineArr. I'll try it without those.

Comment: @rcompton ... how will you do that?

Comment: `BufferedReader.readLine` uses a `StringBuffer` to collect the characters in the current line and starts with a size of 80. If a line is longer, then the buffer's array is copied into a larger one. The old one then is garbage. How long are your lines?

Comment: @AndreasMayer the lines are about 30 chracters.

Comment: @DaveNewton I think you've answered it.

Comment: @rcompton Well, that's something different than what I said; you're removing the arrays by not splitting it--that wasn't what I was suggesting, although if your logic allows for that, obviously it'll take less memory to have less objects.

Comment: @DaveNewton The stuff in the FileBuffer gets copied into the ArrayDeque, so there should be no drop, right? removing the lineArr in the loop stops the drops, but it's no so interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BufferedReader is an abstraction layer that works with the FileReader object. To aid efficiency, it most probably duplicates, or buffers, certain parts of the FileReader's data as you roll through the input.

An efficient BufferedReader, which we hope the library provides us with, would probably discard this data once it is deemed irrelevant. This irrelevant data will periodically be cleared by the garbage collector.

This is the most plausible reason I can think of for the periodic heap size decreases.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. I forgot about the BufferedReader, based on the name, it does sound like there should be a large amount of buffering going on in here.

Comment: However, everything that gets buffered eventually is saved into the ArrayDeque. So there is no decrease when that data is dereferenced by the BufferedReader?

Comment: @rcompton no data is lost, true, but it is not clear how it is encoded in the original file or how it is modeled inside the buffered reader. The reader might store all sorts of extra info for each byte, such as it's index, a timestamp for when it was read (let your imagination go wild here!).